# Dependent dropdown filter

Tags: javascript, jquery

Repeating the question by following the tips of the people and the site. Sorry I didn't do it right last time.

My dilemma is as follows:
I have a custom filter with four categories, all have to be visible, but one is dependent on the other. When I select a "Categoria / Category" filter option, the next "Largura / Width" filter will receive the default values for that category, otherwise it will be blank. And so it will be, when selecting a "Largura" option, the "Perfil" filter will show the preset Largura selected options

I had managed to do with `select` but the customization has to be this and I am having difficulty and come to help, preferably with Javascript

If you want to see the complete project, here in codepen:
https://codepen.io/KaioRocha/pen/RwbRzWR

Snippet:

```js
// Open Box Categoria
function abrirFiltroCategoria() {
  var x = document.querySelector(".box__categoria");
  if (x.style.display == 'none' || x.style.display == '') {
    x.style.display = "flex";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "none";
  }
}

// Open Box Largura
function abrirFiltroLargura() {
  var x = document.querySelector(".box__largura");
  if (x.style.display == 'none' || x.style.display == '') {
    x.style.display = "flex";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "none";
  }
}

// Open Box Perfil
function abrirFiltroPerfil() {
  var x = document.querySelector(".box__perfil");
  if (x.style.display == 'none' || x.style.display == '') {
    x.style.display = "flex";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "none";
  }
}

// Open Box Aro
function abrirFiltroAro() {
  var x = document.querySelector(".box__aro");
  if (x.style.display == 'none' || x.style.display == '') {
    x.style.display = "flex";
  } else {
    x.style.display = "none";
  }
}

// Get the option from categoria and show
function mostrarValueCategoria(el) {
  document.querySelector('.valueCategoria').innerText = el.value;
}

// Get the option from categoria and show
function mostrarValueLargura(el) {
  document.querySelector('.valueLargura').innerHTML = el.value;
}

// Get the option from categoria and show
function mostrarValuePerfil(el) {
  document.querySelector('.valuePerfil').innerHTML = el.value;
}

// Get the option from categoria and show
function mostrarValueAro(el) {
  document.querySelector('.valueAro').innerHTML = el.value;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid p-0">

  <div class="filters">
    <div class="container" style="display: flex; justify-content: space-between">
      <div class="ui-group">
        <span>Categoria</span>
        <div class="selecionar" onclick="abrirFiltroCategoria()">
          <p class="valueCategoria">Selecionar categoria</p>
        </div>
        <div class="button-group js-radio-button-group box__categoria" data-filter-group="color">
          <button id="categoria_carro" class="button" data-filter=".red" value="Passeio" onclick="mostrarValueCategoria(this)">Passeio
                    </button>
          <button class="button" data-filter=".blue" value="SUV/Pickup/4x4" onclick="mostrarValueCategoria(this)">SUV/Pickup/4x4
                    </button>
          <button class="button" data-filter=".yellow" value="Van e Utilitário" onclick="mostrarValueCategoria(this)">Van e Utilitário
                    </button>
          <button class="button" data-filter=".yellow" value="Caminhão e Carga" onclick="mostrarValueCategoria(this)">Caminhão e Carga
                    </button>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="ui-group">
        <span>Largura</span>
        <div class="selecionar" onclick="abrirFiltroLargura()">
          <p class="valueLargura">Selecionar largura</p>
        </div>
        <div class="button-group js-radio-button-group box__largura" data-filter-group="size" id="largura_carro">
          <button class="button is-checked" data-filter="" value="500" onclick="mostrarValueLargura(this)">
                        500
                    </button>
          <button class="button" data-filter=".small" value="505" onclick="mostrarValueLargura(this)">505
                    </button>
          <button class="button" data-filter=".wide" value="510" onclick="mostrarValueLargura(this)">510
                    </button>
          <button class="button" data-filter=".big" value="515" onclick="mostrarValueLargura(this)">515
                    </button>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="ui-group">
        <span>PERFIL</span>
        <div class="selecionar" onclick="abrirFiltroPerfil()">
          <p class="valuePerfil">Selecionar perfil</p>
        </div>
        <div class="button-group js-radio-button-group box__perfil" data-filter-group="shape">
          <button class="button is-checked" data-filter="" value="01" onclick="mostrarValuePerfil(this)">01
                    </button>
          <button class="button" data-filter=".round" value="02" onclick="mostrarValuePerfil(this)">02
                    </button>
          <button class="button" data-filter=".square" value="03" onclick="mostrarValuePerfil(this)">03
                    </button>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="ui-group">
        <span>ARO</span>
        <div class="selecionar" onclick="abrirFiltroAro()">
          <p class="valueAro">Selecionar aro</p>
        </div>
        <div class="button-group js-radio-button-group box__aro" data-filter-group="shape">
          <button class="button is-checked" data-filter="" value="04" onclick="mostrarValueAro(this)">04
                    </button>
          <button class="button" data-filter=".round" value="05" onclick="mostrarValueAro(this)">05</button>
          <button class="button" data-filter=".square" value="06" onclick="mostrarValueAro(this)">06</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: What you want basically is when select one value the first dropdown should closed and other one popup with the values?

Comment: Do you want to change Largura values when someone pick one of category?

Comment: Yes! And Each filter will change according to the previously chosen option.